# Does Suave include tools for database?

Tags: sql, database, f#, suave

Is there built-in way to access databases in Suave?

Answer (score 2):

Suave is a web server library, so it doesn't come with a built-in way to access a database or anything like a sql abstraction.

An option if you're looking for a *framework* that does have a way to access data built in, [Saturn](https://saturnframework.org/) is a fine choice. It's also used as the backend for [SAFE-stack](https://safe-stack.github.io/) if you're interested in full-stack F#.

Under the covers it's relatively simple, the template just lays down a CLI that lets you scaffold out some code and do migrations. And Dapper gets used as your database access library. But it does at least put things together in a template so that you can see how to connect things.